# Reading a document from bottom

Tags: c#, ms-word

[image: At very begining these two blue words are red highlighted. When I click button1(Next),it turn first red word to blue and onclicking again the next one red to blue and so on. Now if I click the button2(prev) then it should turn again red but from the back side or you can say the last highlighted one]I have created a add-in for MS word. I have two buttons. Click on first move me forward by highlighting a range of words. On every second button click I want to go to the previous highlighted word. Can anybody help me in second button functionality. On button click one I have this code working fine.Now how to go the previously highlighted word range on every button2 click??

```
private void adxRibbonButton1_OnClick(object sender, IRibbonControl control, bool pressed)
    {
        object missing = System.Type.Missing;
        Word.Document document = WordApp.ActiveDocument;
        foreach(Word.Range docRange in document.Words)
        {
            if(docRange.HighlightColorIndex.Equals(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdRed))
            {
                docRange.HighlightColorIndex = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdBlue;
                docRange.Font.ColorIndex = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdWhite;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one way to approach this:

1. Use Word's built-in `Find` to search backwards in the document for the first instance of the changed highlighting.
2. Set two bookmarks, one for the current position of the code in the question and one for the previous position. The code sample below is for this variation.

   ```
   string CurrentBkm = "_bkmCurrent";
   string LastBkm= "_bkmLast";

       if(docRange.HighlightColorIndex.Equals(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdRed))
       {
           docRange.HighlightColorIndex = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdBlue;
           docRange.Font.ColorIndex = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdWhite;
           if (document.Bookmarks.Exists(CurrentBkm))
           {
               document.Bookmarks.Add(LastBkm, document.Bookmarks[CurrentBkm].Range.Duplicate);
           }
           document.Bookmarks.Add(CurrentBkm, docRange);
           break;
   ```

The code for button2 simply goes to the bookmark "_bkmLast":

```
string LastBkm= "_bkmLast";
document.Bookmarks[LastBkm].Range.Select();
```

Note that the bookmark name starts with an underscore `_`. This hides the bookmark in the Word UI so that it won't irritate the user in case the application settings show bookmark non-printing characters.

Note, also, that the code in the question could also work with Word's built-in `Find` functionality to search the formatting. This would almost certainly be more efficient than "walking" each word in the document and testing its highlight formatting. If you were to change your code to use `Find` the solution I provide with the bookmarks would still work.

Comment: yes yes,When I click three times, clicking button2 should take me to the 2nd click of button1.......and on four time click of button1. the button2 click should take me to 3rd click of button1. Means one step back

Comment: OK @AmarMalik Sorry for the misunderstanding - I've adjusted my Answer.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience,here it seems like button2 functionality will work for only one click . If I press button2 more than one time it should go to previous to previous one. Just opposite of button1 functionality   Eg. button1_click->1,2,3,4,5  button2_click->4,3,2,1    And I am aware of find but don't how to move backward with the help of this

Comment: In both the question and the comment you say "one step back". That's what my answer does.

Comment: Please can you help me in this??

Comment: @AmarMalik Investigate Word's built-in Find/Replace functionality (Ctrl+H in the Word UI). It can search formatting (the highlight color) and Replace with other formatting. Once it's working in the UI, record a macro to get the necessary VBA syntax. (There are tons of C# examples if you search the Internet if you have problems converting the VBA syntax to C#.) One of the properties for the `Find` object is `Forward`. Set to `true` to go one way and to `False` to go the other way in the document. For going the other way, change the Find to look for the formatting used in Replace.